# Prove $f:\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ with $f(x,y) = \sqrt{|xy|}$ not totally differentiable

Tags: analysis, derivatives, continuity, proof-writing

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ with $f(x,y) = \sqrt{|xy|}$.

I need to show that $f$ is continuous in $(0,0)$ and partially differentiable towards both variables, but not totally differentiable.

To show that the function is continuous at the origin, I use the polar coordinates: Putting $x=\rho \cos \theta$ and $ y=\rho \sin \theta$ with $\rho >0$ and $\theta \in [0, 2 \pi)$, we have that $$\sqrt{|xy|}=\sqrt{\rho^2 |\cos \theta \sin \theta|}\le \rho \to 0$$if $\rho \to 0$.

Since $f=0$ on both coordinate axes, the two partial derivatives *do* exist at the origin, and are both zero.

But how can one show that they are not totally differentiable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the partial derivatives are $0$, if $f$ is differentiable, then $(Df)_{(0,0)}h = 0$. Take the path $(n,n) \to (0,0)$ and calculate
$$\lim_{(n,n) \to (0,0)}\frac{f(n,n) - f(0,0) - 0}{|(n,n)|}$$

Comment: How can one evaluate this limit if the nominator and denominator are $0$?

Comment: You have that $|(n,n)| = \sqrt{n^2 + n^2} = \sqrt{2}\sqrt{n^2}$. How it helps?